# Use Spring JpaRepository together with TransactionStatus & TransactionDefition

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Folks, I'm writing a lib where I'm reading some records from the database, publishing something to Kafka and then deleting the records.

For that I'm using a `JpaRepository` and together with a `TransactionTemplate`. I want to have more control of the transaction and with that I'd like to use the combination of `TransactionDefinition` and `TransactionStatus`.

Although the most examples on the internet I've found the code is using `EntityManager`. What I'm thinking about is if I can use the `JpaRepository`.

This is the following code I was thinking about:

```
PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager = // injected Bean
TransactionDefinition definition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
definition.setIsolationLevel(TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE);

TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(definition);

try {
    List<Entity> items = repo.findAll();

    for(Entity item : items) {
        // send to kafka
        repo.delete(item);
    }

    status.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    status.rollback();
}
```

Would this be possible?

Comment: You seem to be implementing the Transactional Outbox pattern. Any reason for not simply using the `@Transactional` annotation (you can use it easily with JpaRepository)? You might need to handle each item separately, unless you accept that if one item fails, and the transaction rolls back, you might resend all the previous items in the same batch to kafka again.